# URL parsing in Java

Tags: java, url, url-parsing

I've got the URL like this:

http://test.com/testapp/test.do?test_id=1&test_name=SS

Is there any way we can get only this part

> /test.do?test_id=1&test_name=SS

Comment: "Is there any way we can get only this part" - Yes.

Comment: yes ofc. What are you using. Servlets or Spring MVC?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html

Comment: "testapp" is your application context, "test.do" the operation you are executing and the rest - request parameters. Since we don't know what framework you are using (looks like struts but...) ther is no clear answer. Give some more information.

Answer (score 31):

Use `java.net.URL` to parse a url string:

```
URL url = new URL("http://test.com/testapp/test.do?test_id=1&test_name=SS");
System.out.println(url.getPath()+"?"+url.getQuery());
```

Comment: but it returns /testapp/test.do?test_id=1&test_name=SS

Answer (score 1):

Inside your ActionClass

```
String actionName = (String)ActionContext.getContext().get(ActionContext.ACTION_NAME);
```

will give you "test".

```
HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
```

is your servlet request where from you can get all the parameters.
Anyway, take a look at **ActionContext.getContext()**. Lot of thing you can get from there.
Hope this helps.

Comment: ActionContext is not a generic class. Please, avoid this answers type.

Comment: @atrujillofalcon, I don't agree. But even so, after the critisism, can you propose something that do the job? Believe me, I know what I'm talking about - I had the same problem, very rare situation btw, in my real job and that was the best way to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Not really URL parsing but this would do your job:

`String[] parts = "http://test.com/testapp/test.dotest_id=1&test_name=SS".split("/");`

`return "/"+parts[parts.length-1]`